# Non constant harmonic function on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $U(z)$ is a non constant real valued harmonic function on $\mathbb C $ then prove that there exists $\{z_n\} \subset\mathbb C $ with $z_n\to \infty $ and $u(z_n) \to  0$ as $n \to\infty$.

Non constant harmonic functions are surjective and unbounded. They do not attain maximum or minimum on the plane. But how do we formalise this to get the sequence $\{z_n\}$ as demanded in the problem? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Liouville's theorem, $u$ is not bounded above, and $u$ is not bounded below.  But $u$ is continuous, so there is $z_0$ with $u(z_0) = 0$.  Next, for a positive integer $n$, let $C_n = \{z : |z - z_0| = n\}$.  The value $u(z_0)$
is the average of $u$ on $C_n$.
So there is a point $z_n \in C_n$ with $u(z_n) = 0$.  [Either $u$ is identically zero on $C_n$ or $u$ has both positive and negative values, and therefore a zero value.]  Now
$$
|z_n| \ge |z_n-z_0| - |z_0| = n-|z_0|,
$$
so $|z_n| \to \infty$.  But $u(z_n) = 0$.

Comment: good solution but you do not need the mean value theorem for integrals of harmonic functions- assuming $u$ non-constant note that $u(|z| >n)$ contains both negative and positive values since $u(|z| \le n)$ bounded, while $u$ is unbounded both inferior and superior, so by the intermediate value there is $|z_n|>n, u(z_n)=0$; a subsequence of $z_n$ obviously satisfies the property

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution.